# How to extract MSEP or RMSEP from lassoCV?

Tags: r, regression, lasso, model-evaluation, ridge-regression

I'm doing lasso and ridge regression in R with the package chemometrics. With `ridgeCV` it is easy to extract the SEP and MSEP values by `modell.ridge$RMSEP` and `model.ridge$SEP`. But how can I do this with `lassoCV`? `model.lasso$SEP` works, but there is no RMSE or MSE entry in the list. However the function provides a plot with MSEP and SEP in the legend. Therefore it must be possible to extract both values! But how?

- SEP = standard error of the predictions;
- MSEP = mean squared error of the predictions;
- RMSEP = root mean square error of the predictions = root(MSEP)

Comment: What do SEP, MSEP and RMSEP stand for?

Comment: Please provide the definitions of those abbreviations by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lassoCV

```
model.lasso <- lassoCV(y ~ x, ...)
```

one can extract the MSE values by `model.lasso$cv[model.lasso$ind]` and therefore calculate the RMSE too `sqrt(model.lasso$cv[model.lasso$ind])`.

Based on the documentation
`cv` extracts the MSEP values at each value of fraction and
`ind` is the index of fraction with optimal choice for fraction.